# How to easly reformat dataset in SAS

Tags: sas

Suppose a data are as follows:

```
A B C
1 3 2
1 4 9
2 6 0
2 7 3
```

where A B and C are the variable names.

Is there a way to transform the table to

```
A 1 
A 1 
A 2 
A 2 
B 3
B 4 
B 6 
B 7
C 2 
C 9
C 0
C 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on the advice from @donPablo, here's how you would code it.  Create an array to read across the data, then output each iteration of that array so you end up with the number of rows being the rows * columns from the original dataset.  The VNAME function enables you to store the variable name (A, B, C) as a value in a separate variable.

```
data have;
input A B C;
datalines;
1 3 2
1 4 9
2 6 0
2 7 3
;
run;

data want;
set have;
length var1 $10;
array vars{*} _numeric_;
do i=1 to dim(vars);
    var1=vname(vars{i});
    var2=vars{i};
    keep var1 var2;
    output;
end;
run;

proc sort data=want;
by var1;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

The least amount of (expensive) development time might be --

```
Read and store the first row

For each subsequent row
    Read the row
    Create three records
Until end

Sort
```

How many times will this be run?  Per day/ per year?

What number of rows are there?

Might we save 1 hr / month?  1 min / year?  Something will need to read the entire file. Optomize last.  Make it work first.
tkx

Answer (score 0):

It should work correctly:

```
DATA A(keep A);
new_var = 'A';
SET your_data;
RUN;

DATA B(keep B);
new_var = 'B';
SET your_data;
RUN;

DATA C(keep C);
new_var = 'C';
SET your_data;
RUN;

PROC APPEND base=A data=B FORCE;
RUN;

PROC APPEND base=A data=C FORCE;
RUN;
```

Data A is a result data set.

Comment: While this probably achieves the results, it's a terrible way to do things.  You're reading the data through 5 times, using FORCE in a proc append to cause the variable names to change - which is a good way to confuse the heck out of anyone reading your code, and in general doing something that's way more complicated than needed.